# backbone Model url with dynamic parameter

Tags: javascript, url, backbone.js, model

I'm in a situation where i want to populate Model url from Model attributes dynamically

here is my code

```
var MailboxModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults: {
         key: 'inbox',
         filter: 'date',
         orderby: 'desc',
         mailPageSize: 10,
         pageOffSet: 0
     },

     url: window.sessionStorage.getItem('mail_link') + "/" + this.key + "?order_by=" + this.filter + "&order=" + this.orderby + "&offset=" + parseInt(this.pageOffSet) + "&count=" + this.mailPageSize  
    // the output will be http://website.com/rest/users/123456/mail/inbox?order_by=date&order=desc&offset=0&count=10  
     // instead output is "http://website.com/rest/users/1926856/mail/inbox?order_by=undefined&order=undefined&offset=NaN&count=undefined" 
 });
```

or this way? both not working

```
            var mailboxmodel =new MailboxModel({});
            mailboxmodel.set('key', sessionStorage.getItem('message_key'));
            mailboxmodel.set('filter', 'subject');
            mailboxmodel.set('orderby', 'desc');
            mailboxmodel.set('mailPageSize', 10);
            mailboxmodel.set('pageOffSet', 0);   

 var mailboxlist = new MailboxList({
     model: new MailboxModel,
     render: function(){
     // render function is working fine 
     }

 });

 mailboxlist.render();
 Backbone.history.start();
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it isn't working is because at the point where you are setting the `url` property the default values haven't been set yet. To work around this you can use a function that returns the `url` instead.

For example

```
var MailboxModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults: {
         key: 'inbox',
         filter: 'date',
         orderby: 'desc',
         mailPageSize: 10,
         pageOffSet: 0
     },

     url: function () {
         return window.sessionStorage.getItem('mail_link') + "/" + this.key + "?order_by=" + this.filter + "&order=" + this.orderby + "&offset=" + parseInt(this.pageOffSet) + "&count=" + this.mailPageSize;
     }
 });
```

You can also just set it in the initialize method

```
var MailboxModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

   //...
   initlaize: function (options) {
     this.url = ....
   }
});
```

Comment: how can i call model url in collection url

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, by default if you set a url [on the collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url) the models will use that to construct their url.

Comment: sorry if you dont understand i try again  
i need to initialize url like this
 var mailboxmodel =new MailboxModel({});
            mailboxmodel.set('key', sessionStorage.getItem('message_key'));
            mailboxmodel.set('filter', 'subject');
            mailboxmodel.set('orderby', 'desc');
            mailboxmodel.set('mailPageSize', 10);
            mailboxmodel.set('pageOffSet', 0);  
because my mailPageSize and pageOffSet  will change everytime.
i want to make the url dynamic and will use in different button clicks

Comment: let me explain more I have a table which is filled with model.sync through ajax which is working fine. I want paging and sorting which can be done by modifying the url (i have given static url for now). on previous and next button click will change this.pageOffset and on clicking header of table will change this.order in url string
after modifying the url i will look like this: www.website.com/inbox?order_by=date&order=desc&offset=0&count=10" which will used in ajax

Comment: Well you can use the same technique, that is use a function to provide the url in your collection and then in your function you can customize the url however you want.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem in my solution passing all the values when I instantiate the model.
Like this.

```
url : /somePath/' + @key + '/' + @filter

initialize:(options)->
    @key = options.key
    @filter = options.filtes
    // ....  

 getSomeThing:->
     @fetch()
```

Hope it helps.